# Elm lang inserting list elements into parent container

Tags: elm

I have the following types in the model:

```
type alias NetworkList =
  { networks : (List Network) }

type alias Network =
  { name: String }
```

And once I load them, I want to show a ul list in a view function. I have found this kind of solution to iterate through each child in the list:

```
networkPickContent: NetworkList -> Html Msg 
networkPickContent networks =
    networks 
        |> List.map networkRow
        |> ul [ class "my_class" ]


 networkRow: Network -> Html Msg
 networkRow network =
    li [] [ text network.name ]
```

But can't really make it work, debugger returns error:

```
The right side of (|>) is causing a type mismatch.

     networks 
        |> List.map networkRow

(|>) is expecting the right side to be a:

     NetworkList -> a

 But the right side is:

     List Network -> List (Html Msg)
```

What am I doing wrong in this case? Is it reasonable to use List.map for this kind of purpose, or there is better way to show all the child elements?

Comment: Just a note, now that you have the solution. There's no reason you couldn't have said `type alias NetworkList = List Network`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NetworkList is a record with networks as a key. Try thhe following instead

```
networkPickContent: NetworkList -> Html Msg 
networkPickContent networkList =
    networkList.networks
        |> List.map networkRow
        |> ul [ class "my_class" ]
```

Comment: Hey @Simon, thanks a lot! Damn, I can't believe I missed this. Have a great day!